# Problems while deploying play framework app

Tags: web-applications, playframework, playframework-2.0

So I finally managed to start my application on my server without any exceptions:

```
[info] Done packaging.

(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background                   )

Play server process ID is 12205
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/botlane
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

What confuses me is the `/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000`

So the problem is I am not able to access the started server, also I cant figure out how to stop and restart it.

My config file looks like this:

```
# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs="en"

%production.application.mode=prod
%production.jpa.ddl=create
%production.http.port=80

# Default database configuration using MySQL database engine
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/"
db.default.user=
db.default.pass=""

ebean.default="models.*"

evolutionplugin=disabled
```

Thanks for any help this is my first time deploying a web application on a remote server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is not much info in your post. I'll assume you are using a linux OS. That means, you should be able to see the java process using basic unix tools :

```
ps -elf | grep java
```

Secondly, `0.0.0.0:9000` simply means that the server will be bind to all incoming ip on port 9000.

Comment: The output of the command
`0 S root     13350 11900  0  80   0 -  2309 -      22:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep java`
Ok, still when I try :9000 nothing is shown

Comment: OK hours of researching and I still have absolutly no idea what to do. The server does not work, even though it is running, and I have absolutly no idea on how to stop it.

Comment: If the ps command is not displaying anything except the grep call, the application is not running. What do you use to launch it ?

Comment: The application was indeed not running, play just falsely told me it was. I removed the RUNNING_PID file and restarted the server with some different configurations, now it is working :)